# Data caching with LDS

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-data-service

I would like to get clarification on how data caching works in LWC. So according to the [documentation for LDS](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_ui_api):

> Records loaded in Lightning Data Service are cached and shared across components. If a page is composed of components showing the same record, all components show the same version of the record. Components accessing the same record see significant performance improvements, because a record is loaded once, no matter how many components are using it.

I have a page with multiple lightning components where some of them query an Opportunity record using LDS.

When the page is loaded, let's say `component1` loads the Opportunity via LDS (and I observe this in the Network tab of the Chrome dev tools). Then clicking on `component1` results in `component2` becoming visible.

This `component2` queries the same Opportunity record and the exact same fields using LDS.

But, rather than using the data that was already retrieved in `component1` I see another server round trip in the Network tab to get the same data. So I’m confused. How is this data being shared across components if both components fire a server request for the same record?

Comment: I can't reproduce what you're seeing. I don't see another network call when I click a button to show my 2nd component. I'm assuming there's more going on in the components your testing with?